# Make the whole row as a link with JS / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to achieve this situation with Javascript / jQuery. I want to write code that will use this `a href` and wrap-around `tr`

This is an example:

```
<tr>
   <td>122880</td>
   <td>John</td>
   <td>Doe</td>
   <td><a href="/preson/details/42838" class="btn btn-secondary">More</a></td>
</tr>
```

I want to achieve this:

```
<tr data-href="/preson/details/42838">
   <td>122880</td>
   <td>John</td>
   <td>Doe</td>
   <td><a href="/preson/details/42838" class="btn btn-secondary">More</a></td>
</tr>
```

Can anybody try to help me with this:

UPDATE

```
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('tr a');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function (el)  {
          el.href = el.href;


          var new = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
             Array.prototype.forEach.call(new, function (e)  {
                     e.href= e.href.prop("data-href", el.href)
    
        });
```

Comment: Something like? `$(document).on("click", "tr", function() { $(this).find("a").first().click() })`

Comment: Have you tried using [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) ?

Comment: @JeremyThille, I update my question

Comment: @freedomn-m, I update my question

Comment: Bit clearer with expected results (didn't spot the data-href the first time).  Try:  `$("tr a").each(function() { $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-href", this.href); }`  or `$("tr").each(function() { $(this).attr("data-href", $(this).find("a")[0].href)`

Comment: Note that adding an `href=` or `data-href=` to a `tr` won't make it *act* like a link unless there's some other js code to read and use that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, it's as simple as :

```js
$("tr").each( function() {
  const $tr = $(this);
  $tr.attr("data-href", $tr.find("a").attr("href"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>122880</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td><a href="/preson/details/42838" class="btn btn-secondary">More</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```